# while loop not working for blackjack

Tags: python, function, while-loop, blackjack

I am basically creating a simple blackjack game using python. I was trying to do a while loop by asking the player if they want to draw a card or no. However, it is not working, can someone help to figure out? Thanks!

The error is the while loop is not generating the draw_cards function if I put 'Y' or printing the message and break out of the loop if I put 'N'

```
import random
def draw_cards(): #this is a function to draw a card from the deck
  ranks =(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'J','Q','K','A')
  suits =('Club','Dice','Heart','Spade')
  card = random.choice(suits) + ' ' +str(random.choice(ranks))
  return [card]


def stay_hit(): #this is to decide if the player wants to draw a card
  while True:
    playerinput=input('would you like to draw one more card? Y or 
    N').upper
    if playerinput == 'Y':
        return draw_cards()
        continue
    elif playerinput == 'N':
        print('Ok, please show your cards')
        break
```

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: what does _not working_ mean here?

Comment: i notice that no functions are actually being called anywhere. is that the issue?

Comment: @pyjg hi i have updated the post to explain the error

Comment: @JasonStein yes that is the issue!

Comment: `playerinput=input('would you like to draw one more card? Y or 
    N').upper` should be `playerinput=input('would you like to draw one more card? Y or 
    N').upper()`, shouldn't it?

Comment: why do you have `continue` after `return`?

Comment: @jacoblaw yea I just noticed that too, fixed it thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your code works with some minor modifications:

```
import random
def draw_cards(): #this is a function to draw a card from the deck
  ranks =(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'J','Q','K','A')
  suits =('Club','Dice','Heart','Spade')
  card = random.choice(suits) + ' ' +str(random.choice(ranks))
  return [card]


def stay_hit(): #this is to decide if the player wants to draw a card
  while True:
    playerinput=input('would you like to draw one more card? Y or N').upper()
    if playerinput == 'Y':
        print(draw_cards())
        continue
    elif playerinput == 'N':
        print('Ok, please show your cards')
        break

stay_hit()
```

Comment: The `elif` should not be there

Comment: I'm not reviewing what his code does, I simply fixed what it does to do what he wanted. I agree that the code has quite a room for improvements.

Comment: i guess, fair enough

Comment: oh right! thanks a lot @JonasAdler that solved the issue!